# Apple Swift: Generic type constraint for String type only not works

Tags: generics, swift

Very strange, but code bellow does not work and I got a message "Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'String' ". As well do not work all the other basic types such as Int, Bool etc. But it works with Equatable type. What is the problem I can not understand.

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

class Foo<T: String> {}
```

Comment: You can get your Model-T in any color as long as it's black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of generics is to allow our class to be of multiple different types.  We can specify that our generic have some specific aspect.

For example, if we want equatable objects, we will specify this when declaring our generic:

```
class Foo<T: Equatable> {

}
```

Or perhaps we want objects that are of class `Bar` or one of its subclasses:

```
class Foo<T: Bar> {

}
```

The advantage to doing this with a class is we can still differentiate between an instance of `Foo<ParentClass>` and `Foo<ChildClass>`.  If we didn't use generics, and specified our instance variables of type `ParentClass`, inheritance would allow us to still assign objects of `ChildClass` to it, but we wouldn't be able to compare objects of `Foo` to determine what type of `Foo` it is, unless we use generics.  Consider an array of type `[ParentClass]`, which can hold `ParentClass` or its subclasses, versus an array of type `[ChildClass]`, which cannot hold objects of type `ParentClass`.

---

Now, back to your question of `Foo<T: String>`, the problem here is that `String` is a struct.  It's not a class which can be inherited from, and it's not a protocol which other things can conform to.  It's a struct.  The only type that `Foo` can be is `Foo<String>` because nothing else is a `String`.  And therefore `Foo<T: String>` is not allowed because it'd be nothing but confusing.

Compare this to the first example, of `Foo<T: Equatable>`, since things can conform to `Equatable`, I can instantiate many types of `Foo`:

```
let i = Foo<Int>()
let d = Foo<Double>()
let s = Foo<String>()
let c = Foo<Character>()
```

But if `Foo<T: String>` were allowed, the only thing I'd be able to instantiate is:

```
let s = Foo<String>()
```

And I'd never be able to instantiate any other type of `Foo`, so what's the point?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you can't inherit from structs and String is a struct.